# Reset figure numbering for each <part>/<chapter> in an pdf2 XSL:FO(FOP) deliverable

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, dita, dita-ot

I'd like to reset figure numbering for each `<part>`/`<chapter>` element in a `<bookmap>`. I found [dita-users.groups.io/45007](https://dita-users.groups.io/g/main/message/45007), but this did not help me. In `topic.xsl` there is this statement:

```xml
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/fig ')]/*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]" mode="fig.title-number">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('enumerableByClass', 'topic/fig')[. &lt;&lt; current()][dita-ot:notExcludedByDraftElement(.)])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Probably here the modification is needed. But I don't understand how to modify it. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/fig ')]/*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]" mode="fig.title-number">
      <xsl:variable name="thisChapter" select="ancestor::chapter[1]"/>
      
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::fig[ancestor::chapter[1] = $thisChapter])"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This did not help, also tried with "part" instead of "chapter".

Comment: Maybe you need to reduce your content to a smaller sample project with a map and a few topics exhibiting the problem, then start adding some xsl:message's in the template, see if it gets called, if it properly locates the ancestor chapter, the preceding figures...

Comment: Did anything change? If nothing changed, then it's likely that the XSLT processor isn't using your template. As Radu said, put an `<xsl:message>` in your template to confirm that it's being used.